# why am i getting Servlet session variable as null in jsp for the first time and then fine from next

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

I'm trying to load a jsp page from servlet. I wanna access two servlet variables in jsp so that i've used session to send those variables to jsp. The problem here is, in first call i'm getting those variables as null and from next call it works fine. Below is my code.

Here is my servlet code

```
public class sample extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static PDDocument document = null;
static int numberOfFilesInDirectory = 0;
static String isNextPageButtonClicked = "";
public sample() {
    super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    isNextPageButtonClicked = request.getParameter("isButtonClicked");
    String previousPdfName = request.getParameter("pdfName");
    String fileName = "file.pdf";   
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("fileName", fileName);
    session.setAttribute("totalNumberOfFiles", numberOfFilesInDirectory);
    File file = new File("D:/IIV3Project/Documents/Invoices/input/"+fileName+"");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; fileName=\"968396_DCNA_UPGF_MAN.pdf");
         try {
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
            if(isNextPageButtonClicked != null){
                UtilHelper helper = new UtilHelper();
                helper.moveFileFromLocation(previousPdfName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Invoice Batch Splitter</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ReadPdfServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Invoice.ReadPdfServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Here is my jsp code index.jsp

```
<body>
<div class="container row"
    style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 1%;">
    <h2 style="width: 25%">Pre-Scan Process</h2>
    <p
        style="width: 50%; margin-left: 30%; margin-top: -3%; font-size: x-large;">
        File Name :
        <%=session.getAttribute("fileName")%></p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which call goes first ? To JSP or Servlet ?

Comment: @janos i've edited my servlet code. For this servlet class i'm using "@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/"})" annotation instead of mapping this servlet in xml file.

Comment: @javaguy servlet will call first

Comment: From the given data, can't conclude anything

Comment: @javaguy i'm sorry but these are the files i'm having. are you saying like my code is not clear?